# Последовательность сборки CSS в Gulp

Tags: css, node.js, gulp, сборка

Можно ли указать последовательность сборки стилей проекта с помощью `Gulp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Вариант 1

Настроить последовательность генерации стилей в `Gulp`:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src([
        './styl/style.styl',
        './styl/main.styl',
        './styl/home.styl'
    ])
        .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
        .pipe(stylus())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))
});
```

#### Вариант 2

Регулировать последовательность стилей через `@import` в препроцессоре:

```
@import "style.styl"
@import "main.styl"
@import "home.styl"
```

#### Вариант 3

Переименовать стили в нужном алфавитном порядке:

```
1style.styl
2main.styl
3home.styl
```

А затем Gulp-таск собирёт все файлы в один по алфавитному порядку:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
        gulp.src('./styl/*.styl')
            .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
            .pipe(stylus())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))
    });
```

Comment: На данный момент так и делаю. Думал может есть более простой способ.

Comment: @АлександрКоваленко дополнил ответ.